# How to convert Hex to original file format?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `.tgz` file that was formatted as shell code, it looks like this (Hex):

```
"\x1F\x8B\x08\x00\x44\x7A\x91\x4F\x00\x03\xED\x59\xED\x72.."
```

It was generated this way (python3):

```
import os

def main():

        dump_src = "MyPlugin.tgz"
        fc = ""
        try:
                with open(dump_src, 'rb') as fd:
                        fcr = fd.read()
                        for byte in bytearray(fcr):
                                fc += "\\x{:02x}".format(byte)
        except:
                fcr = dump_src
                for byte in bytearray(fcr):
                        fc += "\\x{:02x}".format(byte)
        print(fc)
# failed attempt:
    fcback = bytes(int(fc[i+2:i+4], 16) for i in range(0, len(fc), 4))
    print (fcback)





if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I convert this back to the original tgz archive?

Edit: failed attempt in the last section outputs this:

```
b'\x8b\x00\x10]\x03\x93o0\x85%\xe2!\xa4H\xf1Fi\xa7\x15\xf61&\x13N\xd9[\xfag\x11V\x97\xd3\xfb%\xf7\xe3\\\xae\xc2\xff\xa4>\xaf\x11\xcc\x93\xf1\x0c\x93\xa4\x1b\xefxj\xc3?\xf9\xc1\xe8\xd1\xd9\x01\x97qB"\x1a\x08\x9cO\x7f\xe9\x19\xe3\x9c\x05\xf2\x04a\xaa\x00A,\x15"RN-\xb6\x18K\x85\xa1\x11\x83\xac/\xffR\x8a\xa19\xde\x10\x0b\x08\x85\x93\xfc]\x8a^\xd2-T\x92\x9a\xcc-W\xc7|\xba\x9c\xb3\xa6V0V H1\x98\xde\x03@\x14\'\n 1Y\xf7R\x14\xe2#\xbe*:\xe0\xc8\xbb\xc9\x0bo\x8bm\xed.\xfd\xae\xef\x9fT&\xa1\xf4\xcf\xa7F\xf4\xef\xbb"8"\xb5\xab,\x9c\xbb\xfc3\x8b\xf5\x88\xf4A\x0ek%5eO\xf4:f\x0b\xd6\x1bi\xb6\xf3\xbf\xf7\xf9\xad\xb5[\xdba7\xb8\xf9\xcd\xba\xdd,;c\x0b\xaaT"\xd4\x96\x17\xda\x07\x87& \xceH\xd6\xbf\xd2\xeb\xb4\xaf\xbd\xc2\xee\xfc\'3zU\x17>\xde\x06u\xe3G\x7f\x1e\xf3\xdf\xb6\x04\x10A\x04\x10A\x04\x10A\x04\x10A\xff\x9f\xab\xe8(\x00'
```

And when I output it to a file (e.g. via `python3 main.py > MyFile.tgz`) the file is corrupted.

Comment: What do you mean with "it was formatted as shell code"? How did you get that hex string? Is that a Python string, or is written to a file in that format? If possible, please include the code that produced this hex format, so we know in what format it is and how it can be converted to a tgz archive.

Comment: Thanks, added my full code, please review :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know the format of the data (each byte is encoded as a string of 4 characters in the format "\xAB") it's easy to revert the conversion and get the original bytes again. It'll only take one line of Python code:

```py
data = bytes(int(fc[i+2:i+4], 16) for i in range(0, len(fc), 4))
```

This uses:

- [`range(start, stop, step)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) with step 4 to iterate in groups of 4 characters through your string
- slicing to get each group of 2 hexadecimal digits
- [`int(x, base)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert the hexadecimal string to an integer
- a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) to immediately pass the converted elements to:
- [`bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) to create a `bytes` object with the data

The variable `data` is now of type `bytes` and you could directly write it to a file (to decompress with an external zip program), or pass it to [`zlib.decompress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.decompress) (to further process it in Python).

---

**UPDATE** (follow-up on the comments and updated question):

**Firstly**, I have tested the above code and it *does* result in the same bytes as the input. Are you really sure that the example output in your question is the actual result of the code in your question? Please try to be careful when copying code and/or output. A few remarks:

- Your code is not properly formatted, so I cannot run it without making modifications. And when I have made modifications to the code, I might run different code than you do, yielding different results. So next time please copy-paste your exact (working, tested) code without modifications.
- The format string in your code uses lowercase hexadecimal format, and your first example output uses uppercase. So that output cannot be from this code.
- I don't have access to your file "MyPlugin.tgz", but when I test your code with another .tgz file (after fixing the IndentationErrors), my output is correct. It starts with `\x1f\x8b` as expected (this is the magic number in the [gzip header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format)). I can't explain why your output is different...

**Secondly**, it seems like you don't fully understand how bytes and string representations work. When you write `print(fcback)`, a *string representation* of the Python object `fcback` (in this case a `bytes` object) is printed. The string representation of a `bytes` object is not the same as the binary data! When printing a `bytes` object, each byte that corresponds to a printable ASCII character is replaced by that character, other bytes are escaped (similar to the formatted string that your code generates). Also, it starts with `b'` and ends with `'`.

You cannot print binary data to your terminal and then pipe the output to a file. This will result in a different file. The correct way to write the data to a file is using `file.write(data)` in your Python code.

Here's a fully working example:

```py
def binary_to_text(data):
    """Convert a bytes object to a formatted text string."""
    text = ""
    for byte in data:
        text += "\\x{:02x}".format(byte)
    return text


def text_to_binary(text):
    """Convert a formatted text string to a bytes object."""
    return bytes(int(text[i+2:i+4], 16) for i in range(0, len(text), 4))


def main():
    # Read the binary data from input file:
    with open('MyPlugin.tgz', 'rb') as input_file:
        input_data = input_file.read()

    # Convert binary to text (based on your original code):
    text = binary_to_text(input_data)
    print(text[0:100])

    # Convert the text back to binary:
    output_data = text_to_binary(text)
    print(output_data[0:100])

    # Write the binary data back to a file:
    with open('MyPlugin-restored.tgz', 'wb') as output_file:
        output_file.write(output_data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that I only print the first 100 elements to keep the output short. Also notice that the second `print`-statement prints a much longer text. This is because the first `print` gets 100 characters (which are printed "as is"), while the second `print` gets 100 bytes (of which most bytes are escaped, causing the output to be longer).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.

Copying you're exact code outputted a weird value I've added to the original post, and writing it to a file made a malformed tgz that could not be opened